# bslib rotating icon dependent on open state of panel

Tags: css, r, shiny, bslib

I have the following app that rotates a triangle icon upon opening/closing the `bsCollapsePanel`. However, it requires clicking on the title first from a closed state. It does not recognise the already `open` state upon initial loading. You have to close it and then open it to start activating the rotations. How could this be recognised from the outset?

I have a method to do this via the server. However, I am trying to perform it within the UI alone.

```
library(shiny)
library(bslib)

ui <- fluidPage(column(3,
  tags$head(
    tags$style(HTML("
     .panel-heading .panel-title a.collapsed:after {
      transform: rotate(90deg);
      transition: .5s ease-in-out;
    }
     .panel-heading .panel-title a:after {
      content:'▽';
      text-align: right;
      float:right;
      transition: .5s ease-in-out;
    }
    .panel-heading .panel-title a:not([class]):after {
      transform: rotate(90deg);
    }
        "))
)

,
bsCollapse(
  id = "tag_panel",
  open = 1,
  bsCollapsePanel(
    value = 1,
    "Title",
  p("content")
  )
)
)
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it with slight use of the server to get things started. It remains UI dependent thereafter:

```
library(shiny)
library(bslib)

ui <- fluidPage(column(3,
                       tags$head(
                         tags$style(HTML("
     .panel-heading .panel-title a.collapsed:after {
      transform: rotate(90deg);
      transition: .5s ease-in-out;
    }
     .panel-heading .panel-title a:after {
      content:'▽';
      text-align: right;
      float:right;
      transition: .5s ease-in-out;
    }
    .panel-heading .panel-title a:not([class]):after {
      transform: rotate(90deg);
    }
        "))
                       )
    
    ,
    bsCollapse(
      id = "tag_panel",
      open = 0,
      bsCollapsePanel(
        value = 1,
        "Title",
        p("content")
      )
    )
)
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  observe({
   shinyBS:: updateCollapse(session, "tag_panel", open = 1)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```